# Remove h1 tag if text is null

Tags: html, css, reactjs

```
    <h1>
       @ViewData["Title"]
       <small>@ViewData["Description"]</small>
    </h1>
```

When  `@ViewData["Title"]` is null it shows white space of size h1 tag.
I want to remove that space if `@ViewData["Title"]` is null.

Answer (score 1):

In react you can do

```
{@ViewData["Title"] && (
    <h1>
       @ViewData["Title"]
       <small>@ViewData["Description"]</small>
    </h1> 
)}
```